# Why I See Different Views with same Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I'm designing opportunity Edit page with a lightning component using `lightning:recordEditForm` and `Lightning:inputField`

```
   <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                      objectApiName="Opportunity" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">

 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-text-align_center custom-container">
              <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="OwnerId" />  </div>
               <div class="slds-size_1-of-2 slds-max-small-size_1-of-1">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="RecordTypeId" /> </div>
</div
```

When I'm viewing the output field labels are displaying in different views look at the below pictures for more:

the below image shows the view of lightning application:

[image]
the below image shows the view of when I'm assigned to the opportunity Edit page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute `density` for this component [Record Edit Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/specification). Its default value is `auto` whose layout depends on choice of user `compact` or `comfy`. **This is applicable only in lightning experience.**

**But in standalone lightning app**, it depends on `width` of viewport. Find it in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)

> If a record form component doesn't detect the Salesforce density
>   setting, the fields display with their labels next to them. If you
>   resize the form container to a narrow width, the fields display with
>   their labels above them.

As the width is more you are seeing label beside field, try to reduce the width by resizing browser, it will adjust above the field.